# How does the keyword "select" operate in golang?

Tags: go

I executed the code below which has `select` in it:

```
func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            fmt.Printf("x = %d, y = %d \n", x, y)
            x, y = y, x+y
        case <-quit:
            //fmt.Println(<-c)
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(<-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

Why does `select` stop on the 10th iteration?
Isn't the `c <- x` operation always possible and should calculate the Fibonacci numbers to infinity?

Comment: You read 10 values from channel `c` yet your Fibonacci loop is infinite... this probably causes the fibonacci go-routine to block when trying to send more values.

Comment: From the doc: *If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value. *

Answer (score 2):

The channel `c` is unbuffered and thus `c <- x` can only proceed while there is a concurrent `<- c`.
In addition, if `c` was buffered with a large enough buffer, the `select` would not always choose it since `select` chooses randomly.

Comment: So I could view <-c this operation as "get value from queue" which means that it waits for something in queue to appear? And unbuffered channel can actually store only one value?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers I found this [article](https://www.scaler.com/topics/golang/buffered-and-unbuffered-channel-in-golang/) and understand how channels work
So:

1. Unbuffered channels have size of 1. And also operation of inserting something to unbuffered channel is possible if and only if someone is waiting for him. So `c <- x` would work if some thread asks for this channel (`<-c`). Otherwise inserting is impossible/would be locked. This is why when you are feeding something in the channel and noone is receiving it causes a deadlock. You are trying to put some value in the channel, code waits (locks) for someone to receive, but there is noone there.
2. On the other hand buffered channels can eat several values. You could feed them `c <- x c <-y` and it would not lock, waiting for someone to catch the value from it. Here deadlock can occur when channel is full (trying to push something there) and possible receivers are blocked or when channel is empty (trying to receive something) and all possible senders are blocked.